# Sorting the Row Labels and Col Labels in Pivot Table in excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem to create a Pivot Table in excel. I want to sort the Row Labels and Columns labels in the table.

I also see there is an Display option in pivot-table in excel to sort all fields list. Can we enable this option from axlsx ?